# Why am I unable to pass in a certain parameter for this generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class `Parameter<T>`:

```
@Data
public class Parameter<T> {
    private ParameterType<T> type;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean required = true;

    public Parameter(ParameterType<T> type, String name, String description, boolean required) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.required = required;
    }
}
```

*The **@Data** annotation generates getters (and setters for non-final fields) at compile time. (see [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).)*

Notice, the first field is another generic class `ParameterType<T>`, however it is an interface:

```
public interface ParameterType<T> {
    String getParameterTypeName();
    T read(String arg) throws Exception;
    boolean isValid(String arg, CommandSender sender);
    String getError();
}
```

This interface is implemented by `AbstractParameterType<T>`, which provides a basic implementation for the following methods: [`getParameterTypeName()`, `isValid()`, and `getError()`.] Therefore, I will not have that code here unless requested.

The aforementioned classes are for your information.

The problem I am experiencing is my disability to instantiate a new `Parameter` in an outside class.

I am attempting the following code:

```
(new Parameter<ParameterTypeBoolean>(new ParameterTypeBoolean(), "", "", false));
```

Where `ParameterTypeBoolean` is an implementation of `AbstractParameterType<Boolean>`, and the constructor is the constructor seen in `Parameter<T>`.

The compiler reports "`Parameter()` in `Parameter` cannot be applied to (the constructor). Specifically, it is complaining about the `type` argument.

The table I am shown consists of:

```
Expected Arguments                 | Actual Arguments                
--------------------------------------------------------------------
type: package.ParameterTypeBoolean | type: new ParameterTypeBoolean() (path)
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, or how to fix this problem.

Is there, perhaps, a logical error somewhere?

I have referenced the following articles on Oracle about this issue, but I have been unable to diagnose the issue: [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), and [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParameterTypeBoolean` implements `ParameterType<Boolean>`. Therefore if you want to pass an instance of `ParameterTypeBoolean` to the constructor

```
public Parameter(ParameterType<T> type, String name, String description, boolean required)
```

the type `T` should be `Boolean`, not `ParameterTypeBoolean`.

If you do

```
new Parameter<Boolean>(new ParameterTypeBoolean(), "", "", false);
```

there are no compilation problems. [Here is the proof](https://ideone.com/2GASeo).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me see the connection between the type `T` and the field in the class.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ParameterTypeBoolean` effectively implements `ParameterType<Boolean>`.

The constructor of `Parameter` requires the first argument to be of `ParameterType<T>` type. This means that `T` in this case is `Boolean`. The proper way to call your contructor is:

```
new Parameter<Boolean>(new ParameterTypeBoolean(), "", "", false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra set of eyes on this.